# Thumbnail for next and previous buttons owl carousel

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Does anyone know if using owl carousel we can use thumbnails of next and previous image in place of next and previous arrows.

Example: https://www.solebox.com/

if not, any other jquery slider that does this job would be really helpful information!

Comment: This is the code you're looking for. `var prev = $(property.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).prev().find("img").attr('data-smallpic');
      var next = $(property.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).next().find("img").attr('data-smallpic');`

Comment: Ok but the usage of carousel is like this:                                               $('#slideshow').owlCarousel({
 items: 6,
 autoPlay: 3000,
 singleItem: true,
 navigation: true,
 pagination: true
});   how should i use your code?

Comment: Check my answer. I replicated your example slider to your need. Hope it fits for you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve above functionality from **Owl Carousel 2**. You have to have below custom function to show the prev, next images.

```js
var mainSlider;

$(document).ready(function() {

  mainSlider = $('.owl-carousel');

  mainSlider.owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    lazyLoad: true,
    loop: true,
    items: 1,
    smartSpeed: 500,
  });

  mainSlider.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(property) {
    var current = property.item.index;
    var prev = $(property.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).prev().find("img").attr('data-navipicture');
    var next = $(property.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).next().find("img").attr('data-navipicture');

    $('.navPrev').find('img').attr('src', prev);
    $('.navNext').find('img').attr('src', next);
  });

});

$('.navNext').on('click', function() {
  mainSlider.trigger('next.owl.carousel', [300]);
  return false;
});

$('.navPrev').on('click', function() {
  mainSlider.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [300]);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.navPrev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}

.navPrev:hover {
  top: 39%;
  left: 8px;
  width: 118px;
  height: 118px;
  background-size: 118px 118px;
}

.navPrev span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navPrev:hover span {
  width: 118px;
  height: 118px;
}

.navPrev span img {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.navPrev:hover span img {
  width: 118px;
  height: 118px;
}

.navNext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}

.navNext:hover {
  top: 39%;
  right: 8px;
  width: 118px;
  height: 118px;
  background-size: 118px 118px;
}

.navNext span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navNext:hover span {
  width: 118px;
  height: 118px;
}

.navNext span img {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.navNext:hover span img {
  width: 118px;
  height: 118px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#"> <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals" alt="" data-navipicture="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#"> <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch" alt="" data-navipicture="https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#"> <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" alt="" data-navipicture="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="navPrev">
  <span>
                <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals" alt="">
            </span>
</div>
<div class="navNext">
  <span>
                <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch" alt="">
            </span>
</div>
```